# Is it safe and convenient to store jwt token in Localstorage or cookies and to store the user's data in Context API

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, local-storage

I am creating an authentication service in React and I am trying to find an ideal methodology of storing JWT from backend and storing in cookies or localhost and the data of user to store in context API to access user's data through out the web

Answer (score 4):

It is convenient to store access tokens in local storage (it doesn't matter if the access token is in the form of a JWT or not). You have to remember, though, that **it is not safe**. Tokens stored in the browser are subject to XSS attacks. Any script will be able to access that token and steal your user's data. As of April 2022, there is no safe way to store tokens in the browser.

Your priority should be to mitigate XSS risks in your application (there are some guidelines from OWASP and Mozilla foundation on how to deal with that). If you want to further strengthen the security of your app, I would recommend not keeping the token in the browser at all. At Curity we have described a pattern we call the Token Handler, in which you use a simple backend component to handle tokens and issue secure cookies to the browser. This adds a bit of complexity to your app but strengthens the security. You can read more about the pattern here: https://curity.io/resources/learn/the-token-handler-pattern/ We also created an example implementation so that people can easily start using the pattern: https://github.com/curityio/oauth-agent-node-express

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is the best way just store the jwt token inside your localstorage because every API also has some auth checks so if someone tries to erase that token then your API would fire the error message. And for user data instead of context API, I would recommend you to use redux for storing the user data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how to check if the token stored in localstorage is valid?
I mean to check if is authenticated so I it can access certain routes?

Comment: for that you have to place validation from backend in the api, that means whenever you call any api you have to just pass that token in the header of that api as authorization header and is the token is invalid then backend will through an error that token is invalid

Comment: So basically every API that is created should also be a request before for the validity of the token?

Comment: No in every api just pass the authorization token I am attaching one image in the answer please have a look.

Comment: Regarding storing user's data in Reduxer, when I refresh the page the data of user is erased, should I continue with context

Comment: Tokens in localstorage are vulnerable to XSS attacks. If possible, it's better to use sessions or keep tokens in http-only cookies. The problem is not that somebody might erase or change your token, but that they are able to steal the token from localstorage and then call your API to get user's data.

Answer (score 3):

If jwt token has no private info, it is okay.
Jwt token should have non-private infos. If you want some private info to jwt, then you should use session  & cookies

Comment: If there is an option to use sessions it's always better to use them, as it is a more secure solution than keeping tokens in localstorage. Contents of the JWT should not be a discriminator of whether it's ok to keep it in localstorage or not. Tokens in the browser are vulnerable to XSS attacks. When an attacker steals an access token she can use it to get the user's data from your API. What is in the token is irrelevant. In general, it's better to have tokens without any private info, but this doesn't mean that it's ok to keep them in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use contextApi if you want to avoid props drilling, or sharing props to multiple components with in a drilling manner. It is meant to be sharing props in a component tree.

If your browser refreshes your data wouldn't be persisted , so if you want to share data to all the pages even after refresh consider using localstorage.

You should definitely store jwt token inside localstorage, but make sure to authenticate on every hoc of your components, so your props dont go stale.

Your Api's should be called on HOC's or parent components, where oAuth can be used to check the api url's header and accordingly when something changes your all the child components would get new data.